# windows could not start sql server ( error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly)

Tags: sql-server-2008

When i start SQL Server 2008 in my computer this error `windows could not start SQL Server (mssqlserver) service on local computer error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly`.

Comment: Checking Windows Event Viewer

Answer (score 3):

Check the windows event viewer.

Also check the SQL Error log - if the service stayed up long enough to start writing to that, it may provide some useful information.

Error 1067 is a non-specific error, unfortunately, so any information you can provide from the error logs will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a system which having credentials managed by an active directory server, the issue seems to be your sql server credentials are not synchronized with active directory credentials

go to services ....> open all sql related services there should be five total. change the credentials shown there to your active directory credential. apply and start the process again. this works for me always

Answer (score 0):

Run > services.msc and look for SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER). Right click and select Properties. Click on the Log on tab and check what the service is starting as. If it is set to system, try entering valid username and password. Otherwise, if a username and password is already there (Usually NT Service or similar) change it to System (the radio button). Try starting the service after this to see if it works.