# windows could not start sql server ( error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly)

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [windows could not start sql server ( error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly)](https://serverfault.com/questions/232022/windows-could-not-start-sql-server-error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpected)

When i start sql server 2008 in my computer this error occurs,

Windows could not start sql server (MSSqlServer) service on local computer error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: Check the eventviewer logs and you will probably find reason there. type `eventvwr.msc` in cmd prompt to get there.

Comment: Could not register Service Control Handler. Operating system error = 1222(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100).

Comment: no my disk is empty

Comment: i reading this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/ef306f44-64b1-44ad-b614-aea0e2ea8175

Comment: Already asked on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/232022/windows)...

Comment: i asked in ServerFault but nobody answer

Answer (score 0):

It is likely something is corrupted.

If this is a production box, talk to your DBA.

You may have to run a SQL Server Repair as per this [post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic123137-110-1.aspx).